# Sequence of linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis

There is the sequence of lienar functionals $\phi_n:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $n=0,1,\dots$ on the Banach space $X$ for which the map:
$$\Phi:X \ni x\rightarrow(\phi_n(x))_{n=0}^{\infty}\in \ell^{1}$$
is well defined.

Prove that $\Phi$ is continuous $\iff$ $\phi_n$ is continuous for $n=0,1,\dots$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: One direction is clear. For the other direction, have you any ideas what famous theorems might be useful?

Comment: Banach Steinhaus?

Comment: Indeed. That is it.

Comment: I dont see how can I use it here

Comment: What does Banach-Steinhaus say? What parts of the statement of the theorem have we, and which haven't we already and must therefore find?

Comment: The closed graph also does the job: $\Phi$ has closed graph because $pi_n\circ \Phi =\phi_n$ are continuous (where $\pi_n: \ell^1\to \mathbb C$, $y\mapsto y_n$) and $y=0$ whenever all $\pi_n(y)=0$.

Comment: @Jochen, you mean $\pi_n$ goes to $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$ and what do you mean by $y\longmapsto y_n$? Is $y$ a sequence in $l^1$ or what? if so, then I guess you take form $y$ the $n-th$ factor and it lies in $\mathbb{R}$ but how do we know that it is exactly how $\phi_n$ behave?

Comment: Okay, for a real Banach space one takes real absolutely summable sequences so that $\pi_n$ are real valued. For a sequence $y=(y_k)_{k\in\mathbb N_0} \in \ell^1$ the definition is $\pi_n(y)=y_n$. For $y=\Phi(x)=(\phi_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ we thus have $(\pi_n\circ \Phi)(x) = \phi_n(x)$.

Comment: got it, thanks :D

Comment: One more thing, have we use formally C-G thm here? I mean, having the projection $\pi_n$ and concluding $\pi_n\circ \Phi=\phi_n$ can't we combine the result from $\pi_n,\phi_n$ - cont. $\Rightarrow \Phi$ - cont.?

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution suggested by Jochen is the intended one for this exercise. By the closed graph theorem, it suffices to prove that if $x_k\to x$ **and** $\Phi x_k\to y$, then $\Phi(x)=y$. The equality can be  checked coordinate-wide, and for each coordinate (say $n$th) it follows from the continuity of $\phi_n$.